# How to call a jQuery function with no event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-events

I'm trying to make a dataTable expand on a click to show more information. The problem is that I'm populating the table through around 1000 records so the only way I can keep the more details data (what expands) is to send the data through a link during the looping process like so...

```
var imgCell = '<a href="javascript:storeInfo(&quot;'+theFilePath+'&quot;,&quot;'+theWebAddress+'&quot;,&quot;'+projectStatus+'&quot;);"><img src="https://cubistmediagroup.sharepoint.com/sites/canvas/PublishingImages/details_open.png"></a>';
```

So that makes a image link that calls this function on click...

```
function storeInfo (filePath, webAddress, projectStatus)
{
theFilePath = filePath;
theWebAddress = webAddress;

switch(projectStatus){
case "New Work - Waiting Activation":
    controlButton("NewWork", NewWorkTable);
break;
case "Active Projects":
    controlButton("ActiveProjects", ActiveProjectsTable);
break;
case "Waiting for Assets or Approvals":
    controlButton("WaitingAssets", WaitingAssetsTable);
break;
 //AND A WHOLE LOT MORE CASES
    }   
}
```

Basically this function saves the filepath and webaddress to global variables to be used later one and then calls the `controlButton` Function...

```
function controlButton (projectStatus, theTable){
$('#'+projectStatus+' tbody td img').live('click', function () {
     
    var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    if ( this.src.match('details_close') )
        {
            // This row is already open - close it 
            this.src = "https://cubistmediagroup.sharepoint.com/sites/canvas/PublishingImages/details_open.png";
            theTable.fnClose( nTr );
        }
    else
        {
            // Open this row 
            this.src = "https://cubistmediagroup.sharepoint.com/sites/canvas/PublishingImages/details_close.png";
            theTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(theTable, nTr), 'details' );
        }
     });
}
```

What this does is get the img in the html table then find the row its in then calls a function that opens or closes the expandable data... This is done with  `fnOpen` and `fnClose` and using `fnFormatDetails` to populate the expandable row...

This all works fine and dandy and everything gets passed in properly and loads great but the only problem is that it requires two clicks to open and close the expandable row... Once for the link on the image then another to call the jQuery function. I need a way to get around this and just have it be one click while still loading the data for each individual entry... I was thinking the best way would be to find a way to call the jQuery function without the `.live('click', function()` because that would eliminate the need for a second click.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your functions as follows

declaration of storeInfo():

```
function storeInfo (filePath, webAddress, projectStatus, elem)
{ //code }
```

call on link:

```
<a href="javascript:storeInfo("'+theFilePath+'","'+theWebAddress+'","'+projectStatus+'", this);"><img src="..."></a>
```

The calls for controlButton() inside while:

```
controlButton("ActiveProjects", ActiveProjectsTable, elem);
```

and updated controlButton() function:

```
function controlButton (projectStatus, theTable, elem){
    img = elem.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]; //alternatively: $(elem).find('img');
    var nTr = elem.parentNode.parentNode;
    if ( img.src.match('details_close') )
    {
        // This row is already open - close it 
        img.src = "https://cubistmediagroup.sharepoint.com/sites/canvas/PublishingImages/details_open.png";
        theTable.fnClose( nTr );
    }
    else
    {
        // Open this row 
        img.src = "https://cubistmediagroup.sharepoint.com/sites/canvas/PublishingImages/details_close.png";
        theTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(theTable, nTr), 'details' );
    }
}
```

Can't test, but should work.

Comment: If i do that then all of the this variables fail... It needs to load in "$('#'+projectStatus+' tbody td img')"  but when i try and set that to a variable then do the .parentnode call it cant do it... I need a way to call a function on "$('#'+projectStatus+' tbody td img')" by just running through the controlButton function

Comment: i dont think it will work because this being passed through the link isnt coming from the $('#projectStatus) table its being sent through a Sharepoint services loop that is reading in the value from a list and "this" is defined as the current data being passed through the loop... This is a very unique situation that I cant explain all of it through my post.

Comment: 'this' will refer to the Anchor tag when the javascript: runs.

Comment: But 'this' in that link is the JavaScript this, and not the Sharepoint this. Note that it's not quoted, so it'll be interpreted in the browser as the javascript DOM Element for the link.

Comment: img = elem.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]; This line gives me an error saying the object doesnt have that property... And the alternate one says it cannot read the property .parentNode of undefined... When I alert img it gives me object Object so I dont think the this is working properly @freon

Comment: Move the call to the onclick handler: <a href="#" onclick="storeInfo("'+theFilePath+'","'+theWebAddress+'","'+projectStatus+'", this);return false;"

Comment: try to use the alternative I gave: `img = $(elem).find('img');`

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if I understand your problem right, but could you simply in the end of your `storeInfo` function call the `controlButton` function?

Comment: I could but it wouldnt matter because "$('#'+projectStatus+' tbody td img').live('click', function ()"  this requires a second click

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if controlButton is called only from storeInfo (which is triggered by a click), I don't see why you need a live binding within controlButton.
If it is just to get nTr, you can pass that as a parameter to controlButton from storeInfo.

Comment: I can try but my problem is getting nTr's value out... I cant seem to be able to do that without using this inside of a jquery function... for example... I tried 
var node = $('#'+projectStatus+' tbody td img');

var nTr = node.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;

but i get an error saying cannot do .parentNode on undefined...

Comment: Take a look at freon's updated answer, that's what I had in mind.